# The Requested Scope is not Allowed

Tags: mobile, hybrid, sdk

Building a Cordova hybrid app with the Salesforce 1.5 sdk (iOS)

I've just cloned the SalesforceMobileSDK (ios) repo, ran the ./install.sh script and opened x-code and selected a new salesforce hybrid app and after re-adding the www folder, I get a lovely signin screen. However upon entering valid credentials I get:

```
DEBUG|0|SFAuthenticationManager|oauthCoordinator:didFailWithError: Error Domain=com.salesforce.OAuth.ErrorDomain Code=666 "com.salesforce.OAuth.ErrorDomain 1804 : the+requested+scope+is+not+allowed" UserInfo=0xa5ac9d0 {error_description=the+requested+scope+is+not+allowed, NSLocalizedDescription=com.salesforce.OAuth.ErrorDomain 1804 : the+requested+scope+is+not+allowed, error=1804}, authInfo: <SFOAuthInfo: 0xa5b6c90, authType=SFOAuthTypeUserAgent>
```

This is leading to some consternation. I've done some homework with aunt google, and it seems there was a bug, 2-3 months ago that was supposedly addressed (fixed) in the sdk that resolved this.

My Scope is set to: oauthScopes = ["web","api"];

Additionally, I just re-checked and re-pulled the repo, to try to address this issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sso_provider_addl_params_scope.htm&language=en_US and https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F00000009CO9IAM

We should not set connected app for full access but

Perform requests on your behalf at any time
Access and manage your data

If you're developing a hybrid/web app, you also need the following additional scope:

Provide access to your data via the Web

Comment: Can you update this answer with the actual names of the scopes? Many of these do not map 1:1 to actual scopes

Answer (score 0):

Your scopes are correct based on the docs (http://help.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/remoteaccess_oauth_scopes.htm), so I'd guess either a problem with the SDK or possibly a bug (seems unlikely).

Do you get this same error with a single scope, and/or the "id" scope? What URL do you get on the signin screen - specifically what does your code translate into for the scope URL parameter? (it should be "&scope=web%20api").

You may need to file a case on this one unless it's something obvious.

Comment: the url it's hitting is: https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?client_id=REDACTED&redirect_uri=testsfdc:///mobilesdk/detect/oauth/done&display=touch&response_type=token&scope=refresh_token%20web%20api

Comment: Which feels / looks right but isn't working. I've sent comments on the case similar to this on github but the active SF participant has thus far only asked what scope I was requesting (imo someone indicating he didn't read my comment carefully...)